# what if I use many 'if's and only one 'else'

Tags: c, if-statement

stackoverflow friends, I have been studying C language in college.

While stuyding, I become curious about that there is a technical error if I use many `if` struct and only one `else`.

For example:

```
if (condition 1)

if (condition 2)

if (condition 3)

if (condition 4)

else
```

In the above case, I worry about if the variable that doesn't match the condition of first `if` struct,
it would go "directly" to else, not to the second `if`.

Is my worrying true? or It will never happen?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The *innermost* one...

Comment: Always use curly braces. If they are missing, add them (and remove any excess semicolons). Then it should become clear where the else belongs.

Comment: Your example is not valid C code. In order to get an accurate answer to your question you need to post a [mcve].

Comment: Thank you, I will follow more the minimal reproducible example from the next question.

Comment: Why don't you code this up and try it?   You'd have a pretty good idea as soon as you run the code!

Answer (score 5):

Per [C11 Standard draft 6.8.4.1p3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.8.4.1p3):

> An `else` is associated with the lexically nearest preceding `if` that is
>   allowed by the syntax.

That is in the nested `if` structure it will correspond to the innermost `if` ("`if (condition 4)`").

Comment: I did not consider the nested if. I should have explained this condition before posting. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Your code in the question is a nested `if`. But if it is not, the answer still stands.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to chek each condition in turn uintil a match is found, use

```
if (condition 1) {

} else if (condition 2) {

} else if (condition 3) {

} else if (condition 4) {

} else {

}
```

this is really the same thing as:

```
if (condition 1) {

} else {
    if (condition 2) {

    } else {
        if (condition 3) {

        } else {
            if (condition 4) {

            } else { 

            }
        }
    }
}
```